# forkserver is not reused in child processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

`multiprocessing.forkserver.Forkserver` exposes the `ensure_running` method. This method's docstring states the following:

```py
def ensure_running(self):
    '''Make sure that a fork server is running.

    This can be called from any process.  Note that usually a child
    process will just reuse the forkserver started by its parent, so
    ensure_running() will do nothing.
```

Link to source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/forkserver.py#L105

However, the following code snippet doesn't seem to show that behavior:

```py
from multiprocessing import set_start_method, forkserver
from multiprocessing.context import Process
import os


def child2():
    print(f"in child2: pid={os.getpid()}, ppid={os.getppid()}, forkserver.pid={forkserver._forkserver._forkserver_pid}")


def child1():
    p = Process(target=child2)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(f"in child1: pid={os.getpid()}, ppid={os.getppid()}, forkserver.pid={forkserver._forkserver._forkserver_pid}")


def run():
    p = Process(target=child1)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(f"in run: pid={os.getpid()}, ppid={os.getppid()}, forkserver.pid={forkserver._forkserver._forkserver_pid}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_start_method("forkserver")
    run()
```

which outputs the following:

```
in child2: pid=4378, ppid=4377, forkserver.pid=None
in child1: pid=4375, ppid=4374, forkserver.pid=4377
in run: pid=4372, ppid=2742, forkserver.pid=4374
```

The main process (pid=`4372`) spawns a forkserver (pid=`4374`). This forkserver forks `child1`, which spawns it's own forkserver with a pid of `4377`.

Am I missing something? I would expect `child1`'s forkserver to have the same pid as main's forkserver.

Comment: The docs do say "usually," so I'm not sure I'd really _expect_ anything. In any case, it seems you're not using [`set_start_method`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.set_start_method) as it was intended, since the docs clearly say it should be called at most once, and from the `__main__` clause only.

Comment: The `force` keyword argument is also clearly _not_ part of the public API, so who knows what explicitly using it will do.

Comment: @bnaecker The additional call to `set_start_method` was a mistake, but taking that out yields the same result. I guess I would like to know under what circumstances the forkserver would get reused, because looking at the source for forkserver it doesn't look like it ever would.

Comment: `multiprocessing.forkserver` is not part of the public API, and `multiprocessing.forkserver._forkserver` absolutely, definitely is not public. You're not supposed to be touching any of this.

Comment: It'll get reused if [this call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3317466061509c83dce257caab3661d52571cab1/Lib/multiprocessing/forkserver.py#L116) indicates the existing process is still running.

Comment: That's assuming that `self._forkserver_pid is not None`, which seems to be the case in my scenario above.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I only noticed >1 forkserver was running via `pstree`, so the non-public imports were only for investigative purposes. They still provide important information..

Comment: This really seems like a bug after playing with the source. New forkservers get started for children instead of using the existing one. This happens already with public API only, so it's not that OP is breaking something here. Already upvoted and saw your bug-report, well done!